# Build a Gettext Wrapper

Tags: php, laravel, localization, wrapper, gettext

These days I'm working on two projects based on laravel and I have to implement the localization. So I found out that the most used method is using Gettext. 
I have some difficulties translating strings with only gettext() and ngettext(). I'd build a wrapper able to translate strings like so:

```
fantasticFunction('Hi my name is :name and I have {n, one friend, :n friends}', [ 'name' => 'Luca', 'n' => 1 ])
```

Instead of writing:

```
sprintf('Hi my name is %s and I have', name) . ' ' . $n . ngettext('friend', 'friends', $n)
```

so the problem is: if I'd make such as wrapper, then tools like poedit would not recognize that strings. How can I solve?

Comment: You can localise however you want to, of course, but just checking since you added a Laravel tag - you do realise Laravel has localisation built-in, right?

Comment: Yes but me and my coworker have decided to use gettext because of its wide support

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `fantasticFunction` as a keyword for extraction — this is well documented in `xgettext` docs and Poedit has properties UI for it.

But nothing will help you with that `{n, one friend, :n friends}` thingie. If you decided to use gettext, you need to actually follow its model and this isn't compatible with it. Do have a look at how `ngettext` works and read up on [plural forms in different languages in gettext](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gettext/manual/html_node/Plural-forms.html) before inventing your own approach. You're vague about your "difficulties" with using gettext's plurals support (which is generally speaking competently done), are you sure it isn't just a case of NIH syndrome?